# Can I use a randomly generated number as a parameter to a method in Java?

Tags: java, random, methods

So I'm very new to Java so this question might have a pretty simple answer. I'm trying to create a Magic8 ball program and I want the fortune to depend on the randomly generated number, but it's treated as a method and I'm not sure that a method can have another method as a parameter.

```
public int generator(){
    int num = rnd.nextInt(2) + 1;
return num;
}
```

That's my method to generate the random number, is there a way to use the product of this in another method?

Comment: Try generating the number before calling your method. And, then pass this random number as input to the function.

Comment: `doStuffWithRandomNumber(generate())`

Comment: Thank you, putting it outside of a method ended up being the way to go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while  defining the method you can do normal defining process such as

```
public int doStuffWithRandomNumber(int i){
//your code;
}
```

At the time of calling method you can use generator()  method as parameter

```
doStuffWithRandomNumber(generator());
```

it will work properly no issue